# On Guidewire Billing Center is there a set of APIs to add/remove/delete users from the application?

Tags: api, guidewire

On Guidewire Billing Center is there a set of APIs to add/remove/delete users from the application without having to go the database to modify the table to it?

Answer (score 1):

OOTB there's nothing like this, you could argue that you can import this data with `ImportToolsAPI` but that doesn't provide remove and delete operations.

Such a service would be very simple, so if you'd like this I think you could implement one.